# PHP - file_get_contents() causing server to hit entry process limit

Tags: php

I have a file that is basically a hub for HTML code, which gets (using file_gets_contents) some .html files, and some .php files. No issue there, except theres a lot of this file_get_contents going around. It gets around 10 files in total and responds to the user, the issue is that only now its becoming an issue.

I have it doing this so spare time, kind of a super-global system, for example, all my css stylesheets that are used in all my common pages are put in a .html file and gotten using file_get_contents so I dont have to edit the same stuff in multiple pages.

Just its starting to hit the Entry Process limit (Currently 20) really easilly.

Is there something else I should be doing here instead of file_get_contents?

Example of what im doing:

```
<?php
//hid database stuff and the db functions
if(isset($_GET["hwid"]) && $_GET["hwid"] != "" && isset($_GET["n"]) && $_GET["n"] != "") {
    $hwid = str_replace(" ", "+", urldecode($_GET["hwid"]));
    $number = $_GET["n"];
    $query = countrows("SELECT hwid FROM hwid WHERE `hwid`.`hwid` = :hwid AND `hwid`.`banned` = 0", "snipcbar_authorization", array(":hwid"=>$hwid));
    if($query == $hwid) {
        echo "<!-- ".md5(md5("something".$hwid."-n-".$number."thatihavetoremove"))." -->";
        echo file_get_contents("MAIN.php");
    } else {
        echo file_get_contents("REDEEM.php");
    }
} else {
    echo file_get_contents("REDEEM.php");
}
?>
```

(The files im getting here, like main.php and redeem.php also have file_get_contents related lines).

Comment: Please post your code so we know what it's actually doing. Btw, why are you using file_get_contents() instead of require or include?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Correct, im using file_get_contents as I want the response not the actual code.

Comment: include and require also loads the actual code. It simply includes the included content into the file that does the including. Or do you want to show all the PHP-code on the rendered page?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yeah I dont want the actual code, I need the response, the code of MAIN.php for example is a HTML formatted page with some php related stuff in it (For example getting the .css super-global I mentioned) just so that I dont have to edit it in multiple pages just one.

Comment: still reads like you should use includes, the php will still run just the same as your including it in another php file

Comment: If you use `file_get_contents()`, any PHP-code you have in those files will be outputted as text. Example: put `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>` in the top of your `MAIN.php` and you will see that code in the browser if you do "view source". file_get_contents() doesn't parse the PHP-code. include and require does. And even if you don't have any PHP-code now, you might have later on and then you need to change them all to include/require anyway.